# Dev always behind master

Tags: git

We use gitflow methodology, so master branch, dev branch, feature branches. For release we merge dev to master and release from there.

What is happening is that each time we go to PR dev to master, we are told dev is one commit behind master and we can't merge. So we PR master to dev. It shows no diff and merges fine. Then we can PR dev to master. But the cycle repeats for the next release, even though we haven't done anything to master.

What should I be looking for that could cause this?

Comment: Why _wouldn't_ dev be one behind master? It doesn't have the merge commit.

Comment: "we are told dev is one commit behind master **and we can't merge**." Why can't you merge?

Comment: "Why wouldn't dev be behind"...  If we merge dev to master, they should both be pointing at the same commit (If I understand my git right).  There are no diffs.  But it is making a new commit on master for that merge, causing dev to be behind.  But why?

Comment: "Why can't you merge?"  Well, bitbucket won't let us.  Probably could force it or something, but seems like that wouldn't solve the problem.

Comment: I would expect `dev` in general to be both *behind* and *ahead of* any release or `master`: behind, because the release or `master` will have some final fiddling in it (e.g., a merge commit), and ahead, because `dev` will have additional development not yet in the release or in master.

Comment: @torek we don't do any fiddling on master with the rare exception of a hotfix.  We freeze dev, merge to master and test.  Any issues are fixed on dev and merged to master.  So it is only the merge commit that is putting dev behind.  And it didn't used to.  So now I am trying to find out if someone changed the default merge strategy on our repo without saying anything.  Maybe we were doing FF merge before, which would make sense in our use case I think.

Comment: Yes, you might have been doing a fast-forward merge. This stops working as soon as there's a hotfix though: from then on you get a new merge commit, which puts `master` ahead, which persists unless you also update `dev`.

Comment: @torek yeah, we always merged hotfixes back to dev to solve that part.  Just never had to do it for normal releases.  Gotta be a setting change somewhere.  Glad it isn't some oddness of git after all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using the standard [Git Flow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/#diagram), then you will have a merge commit on `master` when merging in a `release` branch. (Note, in your case it sounds like you're skipping `release` branches for now and instead you just have a `dev` branch which would be akin to `develop` in Git Flow.) So, every time you merge `dev` into `master` you will get one new merge commit on `master`.

From your comment:

> If we merge dev to master, they should both be pointing at the same commit (If I understand my git right).

Not necessarily. That would be true if you allowed a fast-forward merge, but that's not true if you force a merge commit. However, the *state* of `dev` and `master` should be the same after the merge.

Regarding his comment:

> "Why can't you merge?" Well, bitbucket won't let us. Probably could force it or something, but seems like that wouldn't solve the problem.

That is probably because you have a setting turned on in BitBucket that requires `dev` to be fully up to date with `master`. Note this is unrelated to Git merges in general and the requirement isn't necessary if you don't want it.

If you want to leave that setting on, I would recommend doing the back merge of `master` to `dev` immediately *after* merging into `master`, instead of immediately *before*. This way if you ever have a hotfix that gets merged into `master` your process will get that hotfix merged down into `dev` right away, so your testing against the `dev` branch can include it.

Comment: yeah, sorry, not totally git-flow.  Just git-flow esque.  We do skip the release branch.  But we didn't need to marge master back to dev about a month and a half ago.  So something changed... but I am not sure what to look for.

Comment: But it does look like we have it set to do a "merge commit" instead of FF.  As far as I know though it has always been this way.  So we should have had this problem before.

Comment: @Randell I don't know what changed for you, but I can tell you if you force a merge commit, and have a setting requiring `dev` be up to date with `master` before completing the PR, that it will fail every time unless you back merge the new commit on `master` down into `dev`, or you reset either `dev` or `master` to point to the other.

Comment: @Randell Regarding "git-flow esque": One of the nice things about Git Flow is you don't have to have code freezes while you test your `dev` branch before merging it into `master` and releasing it. If you ever decide you want to continue development on `dev` while a specific commit is being tested for deployment, that is when you might benefit from creating a temporary `release` branch.

Comment: yeah, I think you basically pointed me in the right direction.  Looking for changes on the repo setting.  Trying to get IT to get me the audit logs for that so I can verify.  Certainly no one said they were changing the settings... but we know how that goes.   And yeah, I have done release branch style before.  But this team is very small, and the app really ugly, so they rarely have anything they want to merge to dev in the first days of the sprint.  And the freeze usually lasts less then 24 hours, so the overhead of the branch and all that isn't worth it.  I would rather go full ci/ci.